# Java: Thread.currentThread().getName() returns "NO_THREAD_YET"

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, runnable, executorservice

I have a webservice which runs a Thread pool on service startup like this:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
threadPool.execute(new WorkerThread());
```

The Workerthread class looks like this:

```
    class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    public WorkerThread () {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName()
    }
}
```

Problem: Sometimes the threadname is `NO_THREAD_YET` and i cannot figured out the circumstances under which that happens.I guess the `ExecutorService` just does not have any free threats available,but why doesn't the pool throw an `Exception` when it is full and i try to add a new `WorkerThread`?

How can i make sure that `Thread.currentThread().getName()` always returns the id of a valid thread from the pool?

Edit: The class `WorkerThread` is my own implementation. This is just a reduced example code, as other arguments i pass to `WorkerThread` e.g. `String` variables are not connected to this problem.

Comment: which class is `WorkerThread` of? JDK doesn't contain such

Comment: This confuses me, as the worker thread shouldn't run until the service has a thread available for it. A [mre] that reproduces this would be quite nice here.

Comment: WorkerThread is custom class @AlexSalauyou

Comment: `DefaultThreadFactory` used for thread creation in `Executors` produces threads named a-la "pool-X-thread-Y" unless you use a custom factory, or change the name manually. It should be `.setName("NO_THREAD_YET")` somewhere in your code. As @HovercraftFullOfEels said, a `Runnable` won't run until some thread become available.

Comment: My wording was off as it should be that a "worker thread ***can't*** run until the service has a thread available for it."

Comment: And, opposite to your opinion, default executor won't throw an exception if pool is busy, just silently queue a task.

Comment: Why did you delete this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is very likely that you rename a thread manually somewhere in your code, e.g. during some other task which runs in the same thread pool:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // ...
    Thread.currentThread().setName("NO_THREAD_YET");
    // ...
}
```

after that task is completed, the thread "returns" to the pool becoming available for other tasks, and when eventually requested, is produced such an output.

To get a unmodifiable thread id, use [`Thread#getId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId--)

Comment: Not sure why the OP decided to delete the question as your answer is correct. I've helped to un-delete it. 1+

Comment: Ok, i found out, that the app was not renaming the threat itself as you stated but something even more strange happened. The threadname was written into a database with the suffix "NO_THREAD_YET". I didn't even unterstand why that was implemented, but i removed the suffix and now it is working.